# why pandas is giving different result when multiplying by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe to which I am adding a column, that column is the product of row index value and a constant. My question why pandas give different result as shown below:

```py
c = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['a', 'b'],
    index = [0,30,45]
)

c.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] = c.index*60, 3

c.to_clipboard()


#   a   b
# 0     Int64Index([0, 1800, 2700], dtype='int64')  3
# 30    Int64Index([0, 1800, 2700], dtype='int64')  3
# 45    Int64Index([0, 1800, 2700], dtype='int64')  3
```

Second way, this what I was expecting the result to be except I don't want `c` column but `a` column should be as below:

```py
c = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['a', 'b'],
    index = [0,30,45]
)

c.loc[:, ['a', 'c']] = c.index*60, 3

c.to_clipboard()

#   a   b   c
# 0     0       NaN     3
# 30    1800    NaN     3
# 45    2700    NaN     3
```

Comment: This is strange. If you first run `c.loc[:, 'a'] = c.index*60`, ***then*** something like `c.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] = c.index*123, 5` will work.

Comment: yeah I had alraedy tried that, but I was more confused with why adding a non existent column explodes a list into rows and the other way doesn't